# Smallest closed interval containing $E$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $E$ be a closed set. Suppose $[c, d]$ is the smallest closed interval containing $E$. Prove that $c\in E$ and $d\in E$.

This is actually part of a bigger proof - that a continuous function achieves an absolute maximum and absolute minimum on a compact interval. I'm sure this is an easy one but a hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to the standard topology on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Of course. What else?

Comment: By hypotheses $E$ is bounded. Show that $c=\inf E, d=\sup E$ and then you probably know how to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: closed sets contain their limit points. Can you construct sequences converging to $c$ and $d$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Begin your proof with: “If $c\notin E$, then since $E^\complement$ is open,  …”